# Generating a timer countdown based on the number of words of a <div>

Tags: javascript, string, timer, split, countdown

**What I have:** A countdown timer that goes from 3 seconds to 0s.

```
    <div class="sentence"> This is a sentence.</div>

<p>

<div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color:gray'>
<br><span class="timer" id="s2"></span>
<script>
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            element.innerHTML = "<div style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color:#eda1a1'>0:00</div>";
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}

countdown("s2", 0, 3);//2nd value is the minute, 3rd is the seconds
</script>
</div>
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

Change the number of seconds in the countdown timer, to the number of words in the "sentence" div.

For example, if the div contains:

• *"This is a sentence"* → 4 words → countdown timer goes from **4s** to 0s

• *"This is sentence"* → 3 words → countdown timer goes from **3s** to 0s

• *"Another sentence"* → 2 words → countdown timer goes from **2s** to 0s

I already searched Google and found nothing; thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the string into an array, i.e.

```
const sentence = document.querySelector('.sentence').innerText.split(' ');
```

And update the argument to the length of `sentence`, i.e.

```
countdown("s2", 0, sentence.length);//2nd value is the minute, 3rd is
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lawlesss/8qcpr5wh/10/)

Answer (score 0):

// just split the div content on spaces

```
var seconds = yourSentenceDiv.innerHTML.split(' ').length; //  * 1000 for setTimeout
```

Comment: some browsers have issues with innerText, assuming text inside div is plain, innerHTML should work